# Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n, m^*(A)=0$. Prove for any $B\subset \Bbb R^n$, $m^*(B\cup A) = m^*(B-A) = m^*(B)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I already know how to prove $m^*(B \cup A) = m^*(B-A)$, but still can't figure out $m^*(B-A) = m^*(B)$.

m* is an outer measure

Comment: You need to be more specific. Is $m^*$ a measure or a pre-measure?

Comment: I'm sorry.  m* is an outer measure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $m^*$ is n outer measure, then
$$
m^*(B) \leq  m^*(B\cup A) \leq m^*(B)+m^*(A)=m^*(B)
$$
proving that $m^*(B\cup A) = m^*(B)$, where we used monotonicity and sub-additivity of outer measures. Hence $m^*(B-A)=m^*(B\cup A)=m^*(B)$, using the equality you already proved.

Comment: No problem, when you fell that a sufficient answer have been given, you may press the check-mark to the left of the answer. This marks your question as answered, by the answer in which you pressed the check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

If $m^*$ means outer measure (?) then:
$$ m^* (B) =m^*((B\setminus A)\cup A)\leq m^*(B\setminus A) + m^*(A)=m^*(B\setminus A) \leq m^*(B)$$

Comment: May I ask why m*(B)≤m*(B∖A)+m∗(A) happen?

Comment: @梁楷葳 The outer measure of a union is not greater than the sum of outer measures

Comment: OK thank you so much!